# VBA find missing text String and count missing values

Tags: vba

HI there I am trying to put a VBA code to look for a specific string (text) I have defined in the code  located in another workbook find the number of missing values text from the list I defined and produce a report how many values text are missing and if any values wrong do not match the text how many are wrong. this is some of the code I have put but I am struggling to find a code to look for the defined text and produce a report of the number of missing instrument and nr of wrong instrument: Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

```
Dim mypath As String
Dim folderpath As String
Dim filename As String
Dim MyBook As Workbook, newbook As Workbook
Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook
Dim file As String, sheetdata As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim findrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim bottomA As Integer
Dim c As Range
Dim TESTMarketFI2015submitted As Worksheet
Dim FI As Worksheet
Dim a As Range
Dim col As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim cell As Integer
Dim inputbox As Variant
Dim application As String
Dim value As String

Dim bond As String
Dim promissoryNote As String
Dim loan As String
Dim certificatesOfDeposit As String
Dim embededOptionBond As String
Dim repo As String
Dim bondOption As String
Dim bondForward As String
Dim securedBond As String
Dim inflationLinkedBond As String
Set x = Workbooks.Open(filename:="Z:\Profiles\My Documents\MAPPING\TEST MAPPING TABLES\TEST_Market_FI_2015 - submitted.csv")
worksheets("TEST_Market_FI_2015 - submitted").Range("A:A").Select

For Each c In Sheets("TEST_Market_FI_2015 - submitted").Range("A:A")

Next

If value = ("bond,promissoryNote,loan,certificatesOfDeposit,embededOptionBond,repo,bondOption,bondForward,securedBond,inflationLinkedBond") Then
c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TEST_Market_FI_2015 - submitted").Range("A:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

    Worksheets("FI").Select

    Range("A2").End(xlUp).Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial
Else
    MsgBox "Nothing found under instrument"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your `next` under the `End If`.  When it checks the value, it does not know what it's actually checking.  It should be:

```
For Each c In Sheets("TEST_Market_FI_2015 - submitted").Range("A:A")

    If c.value = ("bond,promissoryNote,loan,certificatesOfDeposit,embededOptionBond,repo,bondOption,bondForward,securedBond,inflationLinkedBond") Then

        c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("TEST_Market_FI_2015 - submitted").Range("A:A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        Worksheets("FI").Select

        Range("A2").End(xlUp).Offset(i, 0).PasteSpecial
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found under instrument"
    End If

Next
```

So now what will happen is, it will *loop* through each cell, in your selected range and check the value of `c` (the cell it's presently looking at). If the value of `c` matches your string then it will `do stuff`.

However, I doubt the cell value you're looking for is truly a comma delimited string.  Are you trying to search for all of those strings individually, meaning that if c.value is ANY of the words in your `()` then it should `do stuff`. If so, one option to pursue would be creating a string array, and having the `c.value` look in the array instead.